# Adding url slug to Next Js routing getting TypeError path should be type string getting type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am trying to add an :id slug to the url for a blog post in my next.js app.  It works if i just follow the link from the app to the page but if I refresh the page on the post or directly access the page I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
    at extname (path.js:835:5)
    at new View (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:56:14)
    at Function.render (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at app.get (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\server.js:31:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Web Pages\React Apps\Full Stack\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I have read the documentation [Next Js Docs With Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-link) and am doing it exactly as described.

Here is my code:

server.js

```
nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  const app = express();
  app.use(express.json());

  app.get('/post/:id', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/post', { id: req.params.id });
  });

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  app.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`ready at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Link to the page

```
<Link as={`/post/${post._id}`} href={`/post?id=${post._id}`}>
  <a>Link text</a>
</Link>
```

As per the documentation this is how it should be written out.  I am not sure what steps I have missed or if maybe there is an issue with webpack or something.  If you need more information let me know any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making the `express` app render, the goal here is to pass the request to NextJS.

Change render to:

```
app.get('/post/:id', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/post', { id: req.params.id });
});
```

[Example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js)

Comment: Wow I feel stupid.  Thanks I can't believe I missed that I have been staring at this for hours and now I feel like an idiot.